# Landscape-like tool to distribute security upgrades to OS?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, landscape

i'm looking for an alternative to Landscape, Spacewalk (for RHEL), or CTL to perform a specific job. I need to control and apply OS upgrades on ubuntu systems, for 100+ servers, and so far i wasn't that lucky. I've tried Approx tool (similar to apt-proxy), but it just caches the content, and what i really need to do is set update milestones, apply the upgrades to QA servers, validate, then Stage environment, and so on to Production.
I hope I was clear enough, any answer will be much appreciated.

Comment: Tried puppet or spacewalk? spacewalk does have debian support.

Comment: I've read that on spacewalk, I guess I should give it a try, but it does not make me feel comfortable that spacewalk is based on RHEL systems.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've finally found a suitable solution for this task: Apt-Mirror + Apache. Thanks for your support!

Comment: can you share the knowledge? I'd be curious about how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Options to manage multiple Ubuntu servers are tracked in this question [Options for managing multiple Ubuntu installations together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200824/what-are-the-options-for-managing-multiple-ubuntu-installations-together-and-kee/)