# Installation guide for multiple servers using Cockpit

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management, documentation, landscape

I found this project can handle multiple servers [Cockpit Project](http://cockpit-project.org) but I do not know how to use it. Question is then, is there Cockpit documentation or is there an alternative for MULTIPLE server installations BESIDES landscape?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Do you want software to automatically install and configure multiple servers? The title is asking how to do that with Landscape but the text implies not using Landscape.

Answer (score 2):

Cockpit is in development, and it is a Red Hat sponsored tool - it is not clear today it will manage Ubuntu.

Cockpit's documentation is sparse at the moment as it is undergoing rapid development - you can read the source, but that's about it for now.

Options to manage multiple Ubuntu servers are tracked in this question [Options for managing multiple Ubuntu installations together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200824/what-are-the-options-for-managing-multiple-ubuntu-installations-together-and-kee/)

Finally, if you are after machine deployment instead of machine management, you should have a look at MAAS.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since this thread was created. Cockpit has been developed a lot and now Ubuntu is being supported quite well. Strong points, besides server management, is the integration of Docker. This way services can be deployed, in a single click using images from the cockpit repositories.
Instructions for installing cockpit on Ubuntu are on the cockpit website: http://cockpit-project.org/running.html

Answer (score 0):

I got cockpit to work under Ubuntu 14.04 on a Vagrant machine using this tutorial.  Note, however, that one of the comments (from user RoseHosting) in that link indicate additional needed steps for Ubuntu 14.04

[A remote manager for GNU/Linux servers | Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cockpit-a-remote-manager-for-gnulinux-servers.html)

These are the steps that got it working for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jpsutton/cockpit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cockpit
sudo apt-get install glib-networking
sudo /usr/sbin/remotectl certificate --ensure --user=root
sudo /usr/libexec/cockpit-ws
```