# Managing Ubuntu 14.04 clients alternative landscape

Tags: alternative, landscape

We are migrating some Windows pc's to Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).
For Windows we have a tool to manage those devices:

- checking invetory on pc's (which software is installed)
- pushing software to the clients (batch / bash scripts)
- taking over the pc's

I saw that Ubuntu has a tool called landscape.
Is there a free opensource alternative for this? Which is capable of the things I described?

Comment: There are many such tools available. A few that come to mind are puppet, chef and ansible.

Comment: I Think you can get a access to a local copy to run on your own server in house but you need to first have a subscription for support first. you may be able to just use the trial and get access to the feature.

Comment: In a simular treath I found https://github.com/magenta-aps/bibos_admin

Answer (score 1):

I have found a tool called CFEngine which can be used for free for up to 25 clients.

Answer (score 0):

Options to manage multiple Ubuntu servers are tracked in this question [Options for managing multiple Ubuntu installations together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/200824/what-are-the-options-for-managing-multiple-ubuntu-installations-together-and-kee/)